# Failed to install puppeteer using npm - connect EACCES

Tags: npm, npm-install, puppeteer

When I try to run a `npm install`, it fails at a dependency called `puppeteer`.

And if I run:

```
npm install -g puppeteer@1.5.0
```

(existing in package.json as `"puppeteer": "1.5.0",`) it fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer failed, reason: connect EACCES 104.16.27.35:80
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

but I can access that URL (`http://registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer`) using my browser.

The other dependencies specified in **package.json** work fine. Only this one generates problems.

**Details**:

- npm - 6.2.0
- node - v10.9.0
- OS: Windows

Any suggestions?

Comment: Setting the following environment variable `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` to `true` skipped the problem, but I'd like to have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> npm ERR! errno EACCES

This is a permission error, on a normal day, I will say you should just use `sudo npm install -g puppeteer@1.5.0`, but I will suggest you reclaim ownership of the *.npm* directory by running this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Then you need the write permission in node_modules directory:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/lib/node_modules
```

after which you can run your `npm install -g puppeteer@1.5.0`, This should solve your issue.

**UPDATE:**

I will suggest two other options for you,

1. from your terminal, run this:

   `npm config set unsafe-perm=true`

OR

2. use `yarn add` for your installation.

Comment: I also tried to use `sudo npm install -g puppeteer@1.5.0` but it did't work.
I use Windows, so an equivalent o `~/.npm` is probably `%AppData/npm-cache%`. I added permissions for my username on all `node_modules` folders, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

also sometimes it just takes a while; I used npm install (I'm trying to use formkit but I'm not sure if it matters) --verbose and I'm getting a bunch of

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@formkit%2fvalidation
70085ms (cache stale)
```

so I assume its some issue that requires me to download things that take a very long time. Maybe an issue connecting to the verification server?

Edit: restarted computer, cleared cache, etc etc. Still weird and slow.

Not sure what happened but fixed it by going into my IDE (Jetbrains WebStorm) and changing my package handler in settings to a different nodejs. The one I was using was in Program Files and was having trouble accessing pieces in AppData/Roaming, There was another installation inside AppData and picking that one automatically solved my permissions issue.